# AutoMapper - mapping strings into object of same name

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am mapping between two objects, the source contains two strings called `Animal`and `AnimalColor`, for instance `Animal = "Cat"` and `AnimalColor = "White"`. The destination contains a property `Animal` which is a class of type `Pet` which contains two strings, `Type` And `Color`

Therefore I have the following in my mapper configuration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SrcPetStore, DestPetStore>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Animal, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Pet() { Type = src.Animal, Color = src.AnimalColor }));
```

When I run this I get an `AutoMapperMappingException` complaining about `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping` on mapping
`String -> Pet`

It's like it tries to map the destination `Animal` (Pet object) from the source `Animal` (string) without taking the custom ForMember configuration into account

If I add an unused mapping `cfg.CreateMap<string, Pet>()` everything works but it shouldn't be necessary since that mapping is never used (and makes no sense)

This is in AutoMapper 5.0.

Comment: Can you post your class definitions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MapFrom()` is used to simply *select* the source property for mapping. It's basically telling AutoMapper "I want you to take this property *name* to map to this property *name*, but map the types using type mappings that you have in your configuration.

It is documented as [Projection](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Projection.html).

What you are trying to do is known as [Custom value resolution](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html). Use the `ResolveUsing` method like this (simply replace `MapFrom`):

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Animal, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => new Pet() { Type = src.Animal, Color = src.AnimalColor }));
```

`ResolveUsing` literally returns whatever your function returns and assigns it to the destination property, without trying to do any additional maps.

You can also create a `ValueResolver` class and use it like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Animal, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<PetResolver>());
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) but I still get the same exception with `ResolveUsing`, which goes away if I add the unused `<string, Pet>` mapping

Comment: @st3inn that's weird, but I suspect the error doesn't occur on the property you think then, as that member configuration should definitely work. Can you include further source code?